# How to judge whether a variable is an explanatory variable or response variable?

Tags: machine-learning

I have:

1. The number of customers at each FSA level to my company(where my customers come from)  VS
2. that area's population, income(# of people who have 0~19,999, # of people who have 20,000~29000 etc.) and housing status(rent/own)

Can I use these census information to predict who impact the number of customers to my company? 
When I run linear regression, It shows, for example, a positive coefficient relationship between housing-rent, income(0~19,999) and the number of customers.
So I can conclude that area's income people whose range is between 0~19,999 can increase my customer numbers? So I should target them?
My friend told me that those census data are more like response variables but he didn't tell me whether I can fit into ML as input. 
Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, you can build model and your model formulation look valid.** 
A response variable can be dependent on the hypothesis.